# Android Studio - passing an ArrayList through an intent and populate a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

i'm tying to populate a ListView with an Array that i get from another activity.
The ListView Activity crashes with the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface
>   method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

this is my ListView class:

```
public class CarrinhoActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView lv;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_carrinho);


       lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewCarrinho);

        ArrayList<String> lista_carrinho = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("lista_carrinho");

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                lista_carrinho );

        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    }
}
```

the error points to line 37 : where  `lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);` is

Comment: Check lv after findViewById(). It should be null. Check if the id of the listview in the layout is right or if you see anything red in your layout / project. Check if the id respects lowe/upper case)

Comment: no, everything is allright. No names are mistaken.

Comment: show your code about put data to intent

Answer (score 0):

before you go to this activity convert list to json and then pass this json

```
intent.putExtra("myList",new Gson().toJson(lista_carrinho));
```

and then at your second activity
pull the string and convert it to ArrayList then apply it to adapter